# Print page not taking css into consideration

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, printing

```
<div>
  <div class="dark-pale no-print text-center">
      <h2>To preview and print, press Alt + F + V.</h2>
      Make sure to review all the pages and adjust the page borders.
  </div>
  <div class="container report">
    <h5 class="title text-center">{{mudCheckWorksheet.title}}</h5>
    <app-mud-check-header [report] ="mudCheckWorksheet"></app-mud-check-header>
  <!-- Rheology & Pyc -->
 <div class="row new-section">
    <div class="cell caption-bold col-md-3">Properties</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell col-md-3">Density, g/ml</div>
    <div class="cell value col-md-1">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell col-md-3">Density, lb/gal</div>
    <div class="cell value col-md-1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div *ngIf ="mudCheckWorksheet.isWbm" class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-5 text-center">
        Re-Checks
    </div>
  </div>
```

css file

```
.row{
   font-size: 9pt;
}

.container.report {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.container.album {
  max-width: 1130px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.caption-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cell {
  height: 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

  .cell.value, .cell .value {
      text-align: center;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }

.new-section {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.highlight {
  color: red;
}

.no-padding {
  padding: 0;
}

.sub-caption {
  padding-left: 22px;
}

.text-underlined {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.sub-table {
  position: relative;
}

  .sub-table > div {
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid black;
  }

      .sub-table > div .row {
          margin: 0;
      }

.right-border {
  border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
}

img.logo {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

.table-header {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 82);
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

@media print {
  body {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact !important;
  -print-color-adjust:exact ;
    background: white;
}

  .table-header {
      background-color: rgb(238, 238, 82) !important;

  }

  .highlight {
      color: red !important;
  }

  .no-print {
      display: none;
  }

  * {
      font-size: 7pt;
  }
}

table.printable {
  border-width: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 3px 0;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

table.printable th {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 0 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

table.printable td {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

table.printable td .wide {
  max-width: 100%;
}
table.content-top td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.pale {
  background-color: #FFFFDD !important;
}

.dark-pale {
  background-color: #feffa4 !important;
}

.for-reference {
  background-color: #FAF0E6 !important;
}

.group {
  background-color: #9AC361 !important;
}

.notes {
  background-color: #FAF0E6 !important;
}

.divider {
  background-color: #cccccc !important;
}

.vertical-iteration-header {
  background-color: #EAEAEA !important;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.nobr   { white-space:nowrap; }

table.printable td.no-border {
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style:none;
  border-color: white;
}

table.printable td.border-bottom {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color: black;
}

table.printable td.border-top {
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color: black;
}

table.printable tr.no-border td {
  border:none;
}

div.pagebreak {
 page-break-after: always;
 page-break-inside: avoid;
}

div.nopagebreak {
 page-break-inside: avoid;
}

table.fixed {
  width:100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table.fixed td.last {
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/*psd chart*/

.bar {
  _fill: #1f77b4;
  fill: #9AC361;
  stroke: #333;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis text {
  _font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  _font-size: 9pt;
}

.x.axis text {
  font-size: 8pt;
}

path.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.dot {
  stroke: black;
}

.width10 {
width:10%
}

.width170 {
  width :170px
}
.width155 {
  width: 155px
}

.width50 {
  width: 50px
}

.width40 {
  width: 40px
}
.width60 {
  width: 60px
}
.width80 {
  width: 80px
}
.width75 {
  width: 75px
}
.width110 {
  width: 110px
}
.width15 {
  width: 15px
}
.width20 {
  width: 20px
}
.width100 {
  width: 100%
}

.width100px {
  width : 100px
}
.width200px {
  width: 200px
}

.width160px {
  width: 160px
}

.width730px {
  width: 730px
}

.width25 {
  width: 25%
}
.width26 {
  width: 26%
}
.width1 {
  width: 1%
}

table.printable th.no-border {
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: none;
  border-color: white;
}

table.printable th.text-center {
text-align:center
}

table.printable th.normalFont {
  font-weight: normal;
}

table caption {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

[capture of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdRGM.png)

[On Printing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50svS.png)

> **When I am trying to print the page the css is not getting populated. on pressing Ctrl+p the page should get printed exactly what its in the
> browser, however it is not taking CSS into consideration. I want to
> print the exact page. Please suggest**

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your post.

Comment: How are you declaring your CSS file? (can you add it to the question?) If it has the attribute `media="screen"` you should change it to `media="all"`

Comment: In my component.ts file i have added as below                                              @Component({
  selector: 'app-mud-check-work-sheet',
  templateUrl: './mud-check-work-sheet.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['../report.scss', './mud-check-work-sheet.component.css'],
}) report.scss have the css which i have pasted already

Comment: Then how does it show on the actual rendered web page? (using inspect from developper tools) I have not used the latest versions of angular enough to know the default

Comment: on browser while running it takes this css file correctly ,the issue is with print

Comment: are the specific styles used in your `@media print { }` media query applied at all?

Comment: @media print {
  body {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact !important;
  -print-color-adjust:exact ;
    background: white;
}

  .table-header {
      background-color: rgb(238, 238, 82) !important;

  }

  .highlight {
      color: red !important;
  }

  .no-print {
      display: none;
  }

  * {
      font-size: 7pt;
  }
}

Comment: Yes I see them in your question, but are these print specific styles applied? For exmaple if you set an element with the class "no-print", does it show when you print?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250429/discussion-between-radha-and-kaddath).